# Symfony 3.0 issue with redirect to another Route

Tags: symfony, routes

I have made the following controller on Symfony 3.0

```
namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Method;

/*Request Response*/
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\StreamedResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
/*End of: "Request Response"*/

use Gregwar\Captcha\CaptchaBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;

class PagesController extends Controller
{

 /**
  *@Route("/", name="index")
  */
  public function index(Request $request2)
  {
    $session=  $request2->getSession();
    $response = $this->render("pages/index.html.twig");
    return $response;
  }


  /**
  *@Route("/panel",name="panel"')
  */
  public function panel(Request $request2)
  {
    $session=  $request2->getSession();
    if(!$session->has('user_id'))  return $this->redirectToRoute('index');

    return Response("Hello");
  }

}
```

But when I visit http://127.0.0.1:8000/panel on my browser it shows the following message:

```
[Syntax Error] Expected Doctrine\Common\Annotations\DocLexer::T_CLOSE_PARENTHESIS, got ''' at position 28 in method AppBundle\Controller\PagesController::panel() in /home/pcmagas/Kwdikas/php/apps/symphotest/src/AppBundle/Controller/ (which is being imported from "/home/pcmagas/Kwdikas/php/apps/symphotest/app/config/routing.yml").
```

I do not know why does this happens.

Comment: Can you show `app/config/routing.yml` file?

Comment: This can be closed as Typo: _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers._

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just a typo, look at your route annotation:

```
*@Route("/panel",name="panel"')
```

Did you see `'` at the end? Should be:

```
*@Route("/panel",name="panel")
```